# PHP - How convert chracters like "\xea" to correct "ê" character? (ISO-88591 - accented)

Tags: php, iso-8859-1

I have many characters in a text / json like:

```
\xea = ê
\xaa = ª (I think)
```

How convert to correct character in PHP?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
$text = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\x([0-9a-fA-F]{2})/', function ($matches) { return chr(hexdec($matches[1])); },$text);
```

Edit: Sorry, I just copy/pasted an old code - the `e` modifier is deprecated.

Comment: Return same text:     `$text = '\xea';  
    $text = preg_replace('/(\\x[0-9a-fA-F]      {2})/e',"chr(hexdec(substr('\\1',2,2)))",$text);  
    echo $text;`

Comment: Sorry, I just copy/pasted an old code - please try the new snippet.